# Implementing wrapper functions in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I want to wrap tcl `interp` command and do special handling for some options

My code looks like

```
rename ::interp ::interp_old
proc interp { args } {
    # my code
    # call interp_old with args
}
```

My question is how to call `interp_old` with `$args`. I have tried `eval [concat interp_old $args]`, but it is not working in some cases when arguments are nested lists.

Comment: Can you just give it a try with having `option` as first argument and `args` as 2nd argument like `proc interp {option args} {}` ?

Comment: I have tried. Same problem exists there

Comment: How about calling it instead of using `eval`, that is using `interp_old {*}$args`?

Answer (score 4):

In current versions of tcl you should be able to use the `{*}` (splat) operator:

```
interp_old {*}$args
```

In older versions that don't have the splat operator you can eval it carefully:

```
eval [linsert $args 0 interp_old]
```

We use list operations (`linsert`) to properly handle whitespace in args.